# Gson FromJson returns null. What am i missing?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I tried to use gson fromJson but i got this print => Countries(countries=null) everytime. what am i missing ?

//CODE

```
data class Countries(val countries: Map<String, List<String>>)

val jsonString = """
    {
      "Afghanistan": [
        "Herat",
        "Kabul",
        "Kandahar",
        "Molah",
        "Rana",
        "Shar",
        "Sharif",
        "Wazir Akbar Khan"
      ],
      "Albania": [
        "Elbasan",
        "Petran",
        "Pogradec",
        "Shkoder",
        "Tirana",
        "Ura Vajgurore"
      ]
    }
""".trimIndent()

        val countries = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Countries::class.java)
        println(countries)
```

Comment: Your JSON doesn't contain a "countries" key. What did you expect? You need to match your POJO to the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

It couldn't find the `countries` key. There are basically 3 options here.

1. You can modify json itself:

```
val jsonString = """
{
  "countries": {
    "Afghanistan": [
      "Herat",
      "Kabul",
      "Kandahar",
      "Molah",
      "Rana",
      "Shar",
      "Sharif",
      "Wazir Akbar Khan"
    ],
    "Albania": [
      "Elbasan",
      "Petran",
      "Pogradec",
      "Shkoder",
      "Tirana",
      "Ura Vajgurore"
    ]
  }
}
""".trimIndent()
```

2. Alternatively, you can change an entity you deserialize to (e.g. use `object : TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {}.type` as the second parameter).
3. Another option is to create a custom deserializer for your existing json and `Countries` class as follows:

```
val countriesDeserializer =
    JsonDeserializer { json, _, context ->
        Countries(
            context.deserialize(json, object : TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {}.type)
        )
    }
```

And use `GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Countries::class.java, countriesDeserializer).create()` instead of simply `Gson()`

Comment: The input is unlikely to change. Wouldn't it be better to change the POJO itself?

Comment: @Jorn updated the answer

Comment: Regarding 2: Starting with Gson 2.10 you can omit the `.type` call and directly pass the `TypeToken` to `Gson.fromJson`; this provides better type-safety. (Also a bit off-topic, but I don't understand why your answer was getting downvoted; it is a good answer, especially since it offers multiple possible solutions.)

Comment: @Marcono1234 I suppose the older version of the answer might have been downvoted because I initially suggested only solution 1, and edited it later.

Answer (score 0):

To determine type

```
val countryCityType = object : TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {}.type
```

Gson parse

```
val countryCityData: Map<String, List<String>> = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, countryCityType)

println(countryCityData)
```